# Importar módulo que lee ruta relativa en Python

Tags: python

Tengo un módulo que necesita acceder a un archivo .txt; el problema es que cuando importo el módulo, cambia el path absoluto y ya no tiene acceso a ese .txt relativo, por ejemplo:

```
carpeta_principal
|
|----scripts
|    |
|    |----modulo_importar.py
|    |----Utilities
|         |----archivo.txt
|    
|
|----modulo_actual.py
```

Por ejemplo para importar el "modulo_importar" desde "modulo_actual" lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
from scripts.modulo_importar import my_function
```

Dentro del módulo a importar habría un código como el siguiente:

```
path = "Utilities/archivo.txt"
def my_function(path):
    return loquesea
```

Al importar el módulo desde un sitio distinto, cambia la ruta de *archivo.txt*.

He probado a cambiar el path con un "scripts/Utilities/archivo.txt" pero esta solución solo sirve si importo el módulo desde la carpeta principal, me gustaría poder hacerlo independientemente de desde qué carpeta se importe.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes añadir la ruta al path, para que siempre partas de la misma raiz de la siguiente forma.

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append("/".join(os.path.dirname(__file__).split('/')[:-1]))
```

## Explicación

- `sys.path.append()`: Agrega la ruta que le pasemos a la lista de rutas de módulos (es decir donde se encuentran los paquetes que instalamos.
- `__file__`: es un **atributo especial** en Python, que nos indica cual la dirección absoluta del archivo que estamos ejecutando.
- `os.path.dirname()`: una función que le pasamos la dirección de un archivo y nos devuelve la carpeta en la que se encuentra.
- `split()`: este método perteneciente a los **strings** nos divide un string con el divisor que le pasemos, en este caso la barra **/**. Es decir dividimos nuestra dirección por cada carpeta que vamos accediendo.
- `[:-1]`: como tu dirección después de las operaciones anteriores será, `../carpeta_principal/scripts`, hacemos **slicing** para quedarnos solo con **carpeta_principal**
- `'/'.join()`: por último usamos el método join, para unir la lista de strings y quedarnos con un solo string.

**En resumen** cogemos la dirección del fichero, le hacemos la modificaciones oportunas para que sea la dirección que nosotros queremos, y la agregamos al path.

Comment: Un ejemplo de lo que es una buena explicación.

Comment: No me queda claro de que fichero estás hablando en que momento. ¿Hablas del modulo que deseo importar? ¿Del modulo que estoy importando? ¿Del path del archivo que abre el modulo que importo?

Comment: Como no me queda muy claro en tu pregunta, cual es el archivo que importa el ```.txt``` he usado ```modulo_importar.py``` como ejemplo en todo momento. Lo importante es la explicación y que entiendas que se hace en cada caso, para que lo puedas aplicar a cualquier script. Pero

Comment: Muchas gracias @CandidMoe ! Siempre es un halago recibir parabienes de la comunidad!!

Answer (score -1):

Esta ha sido la solución que he encontrado:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
path = str(Path(os.path.realpath(__file__)).parent)+"\\archivo.txt"
```

Comment: Esto es una respuesta? pense que te habian dado una ya... por favor mira [answer]