# Como puedo ejecutar un codigo en un proyecto Django sin usar el shell?

Tags: python, django

soy nueva usando python/django y tengo una pregunta que no logro entender.

Acabo de crear un proyecto en Django y quiero guardar un registro basico como es  nombre y apellido de un empleado, nada del otro mundo, es mi primer proyecto en django, pero no quiero usar el shell debido a que no puedo colcoar puntos de interrupcion para darle seguimiento a la ejecucion del codigo, estoy viendo varios videos en youtube, de diferentes canales y todos usan el shell;
es posible ejecutar un determinando codigo en djando sin usar el shell?

Mi codigo se ve asi:

proyecto django = api

Aplicacion django = employee

**employee.models.py**

```
employee.models

from django.db import models
# Create your models here.


class Employee(models.Model):
    name_one = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    surname_one = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "employe_information"
```

**employee.seed.py**

```
from .models import Employee


class Seed:

    def employee_register(self):
        emp = Employee()
        emp.name_one = "ejemplo nombre"
        emp.surname_one = "ejemplo apellido"
        emp.save()
        print("Nuevo registro guardado.")

    def employee_list(self):
        emp_list = Employee.objects.all()
        print(emp_list)
```

**api.manage.py**

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
    """Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
    import os
    import sys
    from .employee.seed import Seed
    
    
    def main():
        """Run administrative tasks."""
        os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'api.settings')
        try:
            from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
        except ImportError as exc:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            ) from exc
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
        seed = Seed()
        seed.employee_register()
        seed.employee_list()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

En el archivo api.mange.py tiene una funcion main o principal el cual levanta el proyecto django, en este archivo estoy instanciando el objeto seed
para luego llamar al metodo registro y luego me imprima la lista de  empleados

```
seed = Seed()
seed.employee_register()
seed.employee_list()
```

me da el siguiente error:

> Exception has occurred: ImportError
> attempted relative import with no known parent package
> File "C:\GitHub\django\backend\api\manage.py", line 5, in 
> from .employee.seed import Seed

Me pueden orientar por favor, gracias.

Rutas:

```
C:\GitHub\django\backend\api (proyecto django)
C:\GitHub\django\backend\api\manage.py(proyecto django)
C:\GitHub\django\backend\api\employee(aplicacion django)
C:\GitHub\django\backend\api\employee\seed.py
C:\GitHub\django\backend\api\employee\models.py
```

```
django
├─ .gitignore
├─ backend
│  └─ api
│     ├─ api
│     │  ├─ asgi.py
│     │  ├─ settings.py
│     │  ├─ urls.py
│     │  ├─ wsgi.py
│     │  └─ __init__.py
│     ├─ employee
│     │  ├─ admin.py
│     │  ├─ apps.py
│     │  ├─ migrations
│     │  │  ├─ 0001_initial.py
│     │  │  └─ __init__.py
│     │  ├─ models.py
│     │  ├─ seed.py
│     │  ├─ serializers.py
│     │  ├─ tests.py
│     │  ├─ views.py
│     │  └─ __init__.py
│     ├─ manage.py
│     └─ prueba.py
├─ installWithPIP.txt
├─ python.ipynb
└─ README.md
```

Comment: Lo que tienes es un error al 8mportar uno de tus archivos, podrías poner la estructura de directorios que tienes?

Comment: Como puedo copiar toda la ruta o tree de la carpeta contenedora de mi proyecto django ? 

Ahí coloque las rutas principales

Comment: puedes leer esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/385959/183782)

Comment: No entiendo por que tengo que especificarle la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo.

No se supone que el detecta automaticamente la ruta con solo un archivo __init__.py en el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo? como hace entoces para detectar archivos como "aplicacion.models" no veo que este especificada la ruta de dicho archivo en algun sitio/

Es mas en el archivo manage.py 
Cuando estoy escribiendo la ruta de mi archivo el intellisense de vs code me lo autocompleta
"from .employee.seed import Seed" no entiendo de verdad

Comment: Todo los archivos se encuentra ordenados dentro de la carpeta del proyecto django, no tienen rutas con mucha profundidad
cuando ejecuto python manage.py startapp nombreDeLaApp se crea en el mismo directorio o a la misma altura de manage.py

Comment: Lo siento no había visto bien la estructura, me era muy difícil entenderlo, pero con el gráfico ahora lo tengo más claro, solo quita el punto, debe quedar así `from employee.seed import Seed`

Comment: si quito el punto me marca error "Import employee.seed" could not be resolved Pylance report MissingImports"